# neo4j shut down from browser

Tags: neo4j, shutdown

I am trying to use ne04j from browser "http://localhost:7474/browser/". In the query area when I type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (or in any form of upper/lower case) the server does not shut down, rather shows an exception:

> "Neo.ClientError.Statement.InvalidSyntax",

along with a message

> "Invalid input 'T': expected 'r/R' (line 1, column 2 (offset: 1))
>   "CTRL-C"".

Can someone help me by telling what am I missing here?
I started the neo4j using Neo4j.bat inside ...\neo4j-enterprise-2.3.0\bin and I am using windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you started from the bat-file you have to "ctrl-c" from within the black shell window that's opening on start.

Neo4j is not meant to be shut down from the browser, the only thing that you can terminate are transactions/queries by clicking the (X) on the top right.